# mgcv_1.8-24: "fREML" or "REML" method of bam() gives wrong explained deviance

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

Fitting the same model with `bam` using methods "fREML" and "REML" gave me close results, but the deviance explained is rather different as returned by `summary.gam`.

With "fREML" the quantity is ~3.5% (not good) while with "REML" it is ~50% (not that bad). How can it be possible? Which one is correct?

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a simple reproducible example.

```
#######################################
## method = "fREML", discrete = TRUE ##
#######################################

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 
Formula:
ObsOrRand ~ s(Var1, k = 3) + s(RandomVar, bs = "re")  
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 
(Intercept)  -5.0026     0.2199  -22.75   <2e-16  
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value 
s(Var1)          1.00  1.001  17.54 2.82e-05 
s(RandomVar)     16.39 19.000 145.03  < 2e-16  
R-sq.(adj) =  0.00349   Deviance explained = 3.57%
fREML = 2.8927e+05  Scale est. = 1         n = 312515
```

---

```
########################################
## method = "fREML", discrete = FALSE ##
########################################

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 
Formula:
ObsOrRand ~ s(Var1, k = 3) + s(RandomVar, bs = "re")  
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 
(Intercept)  -4.8941     0.2207  -22.18   <2e-16  
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value 
s(Var1)          1.008  1.016  17.44 3.09e-05 
s(RandomVar)     16.390 19.000 144.86  < 2e-16  
R-sq.(adj) =  0.00349   Deviance explained = 3.57%
fREML = 3.1556e+05  Scale est. = 1         n = 312515
```

---

```
#####################################################
## method = "REML", discrete method not applicable ##
#####################################################

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 
Formula:
ObsOrRand ~ s(Var1, k = 3) + s(RandomVar, bs = "re")  
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 
(Intercept)  -4.8928     0.2205  -22.19   <2e-16  
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value 
s(Var1)          1.156  1.278  16.57 8.53e-05 
s(RandomVar)     16.379 19.000 142.60  < 2e-16  
R-sq.(adj) =  0.0035   Deviance explained = 50.8%
-REML = 3.1555e+05  Scale est. = 1         n = 312515
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue can be back tracked to `mgcv_1.8-23`. Its *changlog* for reads:

```
* bam extended family extension had introduced a bug in null deviance 
  computation for Gaussian additive case when using methods other than fREML 
  or GCV.Cp. Fixed.
```

It now turns out that the patch is successful for Gaussian case, but not for non-Gaussian cases.

---

Let me first provide a reproducible example, as your question does not have one.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(1000)
## the linear predictor is a 3rd degree polynomial
p <- binomial()$linkinv(0.5 + poly(x, 3) %*% rnorm(3) * 20)
## p is well spread out on (0, 1); check `hist(p)`
y <- rbinom(1000, 1, p)

library(mgcv)
#Loading required package: nlme
#This is mgcv 1.8-24. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.

fREML <- bam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 8), family = binomial(), method = "fREML")
REML <- bam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 8), family = binomial(), method = "REML")
GCV <- bam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 8), family = binomial(), method = "GCV.Cp")

## explained.deviance = (null.deviance - deviance) / null.deviance
## so in this example we get negative explained deviance for "REML" method

unlist(REML[c("null.deviance", "deviance")])
#null.deviance      deviance 
#     181.7107     1107.5241 

unlist(fREML[c("null.deviance", "deviance")])
#null.deviance      deviance 
#     1357.936      1107.524 

unlist(GCV[c("null.deviance", "deviance")])
#null.deviance      deviance 
#     1357.936      1108.108
```

Null deviance can't be smaller than deviance (TSS can not be smaller than RSS), so "REML" method of `bam` fails to return the correct Null deviance here.

I have located the problem at line 1350 of `mgcv_1.8-24/R/bam.r`:

```
object$family <- object$fitted.values <- NULL
```

Actually, it should be

```
object$null.deviance <- object$fitted.values <- NULL
```

For methods other than "GCV.Cp" and "fREML", `bam` relies on `gam` for estimation, after reducing the large `n x p` model matrix to a `p x p` matrix (`n`: number of data; `p`: number of coefficients). Since this new model matrix does not have a natural interpretation, many quantities returned by `gam` should be invalidated (apart from estimated smooth parameters). It was a typo for Simon to put `family`.

I build a patched version and it turns out to fix the bug. I will tell Simon to get it fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks to have taken time to investigate ...unfortunately for me it seems to say that my model is very bad ...

Comment: @李哲源So what should I take into account ?

Comment: Excellent ! @李哲源 I will accept this answer, but before I do it, can you tell me what other indice I should use if the explained deviance is not informative for logistic regression ?

Comment: OK, I will check. Thanks again @李哲源